# How to use Variable Lookup_array with Xmatch formula, =XMATCH(Student_Name,$B$3:B216,0,-1)

Tags: excel-formula, index-match

I am using and excel to make student exam marks record to see progress, keeping latest three records, last record is perfectly shown using XMATCH but second last or third last having error,

XMATCH consider first LOOKUP_ARRAY reference only but I want all reference should be taken from last one using named range or $B$3:B216 should updated by $B$3:L1, L2, L3……. Value like:

Result                      Lookup_array            Limit Range by existing value

XMATCH(Student_Name,$B$3:B216,0,-1)................$B$3:B216................where L2 is 216
XMATCH(Student_Name,$B$3:B235,0,-1)................$B$3:B235................where L3 is 236
XMATCH(Student_Name,$B$3:B180,0,-1)................$B$3:B180................where L4 is 180
XMATCH(Student_Name,$B$3:B513,0,-1)................$B$3:B513................where L5 is 513
XMATCH(Student_Name,$B$3:B43,0,-1)...................$B$3:B43..................where L6 is 43
XMATCH(Student_Name,$B$3:B296,0,-1)................$B$3:B296................where L7 is 296
XMATCH(Student_Name,$B$3:B415,0,-1)................$B$3:B415................where L8 is 415
XMATCH(Student_Name,$B$3:B319,0,-1)................$B$3:B319................where L9 is 319

Name ranged required for only one formula calculates all column

tired =XMATCH(Student_Name,$B$3:B216,0,-1)

and

=XMATCH(Student_Name,Latest_Marks,0,-1) but not works,         // Latest_Marks Named Ranged for “L column / Range limit”

Copy of sheet attached here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yCuMZiYkkhKZWZQIKqDYT97aos7Jb-7M/edit?usp=share_link&ouid=116840440138009717475&rtpof=true&sd=true

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calculating the row of the latest match and excluding that from the range you could switch to using `FILTER` combined with `SORTBY`:

```
=LET(sorted,SORTBY(HSTACK(Test_Student_Name,Test_Marks),D3:D219,-1),
     name,INDEX(sorted,,1),
     mark,INDEX(sorted,,2),
DROP(
     REDUCE(0,Student_Name,
     LAMBDA(x,y,
            VSTACK(x,
                   TRANSPOSE(
                             TAKE(
                                  FILTER(mark,name=y),
                                  3))))),
     1))
```

[image]

First sorted makes sure the data of `Test_Student_Name` and `Test_Mark` ate sorted by the Test_Dates *(this isn't currently a named range, so I referenced the actual range in the formula.  `HSTACK(Test_Student_Name,Test_Mark)` could be replaced with `B3:B219`)*

I then split them in `name` and `mark` for readability and later use in the formula.

The `DROP/REDUCE` formula behaves like a 2D spill of the BYROW function, so we can spill the transposed filter result of the sorted marks, where the sorted student name equals the current `Student_Name` of that row. This would result in each grade for that student. Wrapping it in `TAKE(FilteredSortedMarks,3)` results in the first 3 marks of the sorted data new to old for given student.